# Square terrain recurrence derivation

Tags: algorithm, recursion

You have a square terrain with area A > 0.  You want to add information into the terrain.  You want to subdivide the terrain into 4 quadrants, process them individually, and assemble the results.  To process, you divide a quadrant further until the sub-quadrants have area <= A0, where you can then add information to the terrain- all in total of i*A time for i > 0.  Each subdivision step results in each of the four quadrants containing 1/3 the area.  If T(A) is the time to label a terrain of area A, what is its recurrence?

I have an answer as 4T((A/A0)/3)+iA, but I don't understand how it was derived.  Can someone explain how each component of the problem relates to an addition in the final result?  I understand the 4 recursive calls, but not much after that.

Comment: How can subdividing an area into four quadrants result in each quadrant containing 1/3 of the area? That would mean the total area is 4/3, which is bigger than the original...?

Comment: Subquadrants may overlap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `T(A`) is the time to label a terrain of area `A` then lets calculate `T(A)` recursively:

- When the area of analysed `A` is smaller or equal than `A0` (`A <= A0`) then we have that `T(A) = c` for some constant `c` since we are not subdividing any more. From your statement I think we can assume that `T(A) = i*A (if A <= A0)`
- When the area `A` is bigger than `A0` then we first divide `A` into four sub quadrants of area `A/3` each, process them and finally gather all the information of the terrain thus `T(A) = 4*T(A/3) + i*A (if A > A0)`

Thus the final recurrence can be written as:

```
T(A) = i*A               (A <= A0)
T(A) = 4*T(A/3) + i*A    (A >  A0)
```

**Note:** I think that the formula you gave `T(A) = 4*T((A/A0)/3) + i*A` is not entirely correct since you would be dividing `A` by `3*A0` which can be much bigger than `3`. `A0` is just used to treat cases for which the sub quadrants area is smaller than `A0`.